# Rimé movement and Theravada

Tags: theravada, tibetan-buddhism

I know that Tibetan Buddhism has the Rime movement, which is positioned as non-sectarian Buddhism. But I like Theravada methods. Can I practice Theravada while staying within Tibetan Buddhism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine you are learning to play a piano.

As an absolute beginner, you start by learning the notes, and practicing the scales.

Then as a novice, you learn to read the musical notation, and play the notes as you read them.

Then as an intermediate, you learn to play the entire musical pieces in the right tempo, without faulting in the middle.

Then as an intermediate-advanced, you learn to place the proper emphasis, accents, pauses, crescendos, and so on.

Then as an advanced, you learn to read the feeling the composer put in his piece, and express that feeling in your performance.

Then as very advanced, you learn to tweak the feeling to create customized performances of the original music, expressing your own interpretation of the works, and your own artistic vision.

And then as a master, you get to improvisation and writing your own music.

So, for example, as an advanced student, when you go to your teacher and sit down for a lesson, she will not even mention anything about the notes or scales or tonalities. She'll likely speak about sparkles and drama, and relief - teaching you to discern the tiniest aspects of the feeling you put in your performance. If you try to speak about the notes, she'll probably give you a strange look and (nicely) suggest that perhaps you should finish your beginner and intermediate training first.

Similarly, in Buddhism, and especially in the Rime movement that tries to harmonize all the different schools, there's a progression of levels. First, there is a coarse separation into Hinayana, Mahayana, and Vajrayana. And then within the Vajrayana there are up to a dozen sublevels.

From Tibetan Buddhism perspective, Theravada falls into the Hinayana level, at least most of it does, except the most advanced teachings on signlessness, emptiness, positionlessness etc. - which exist in the Theravada's Canon but are classified as Mahayana.

The Mahayana level is focused on these teachings almost exclusively, but also on integrating the teachings deep into the regular life. Compare to the intermediate piano player.

And then, at the Vajrayana levels, we gradually approach teachings on energy, subconscious mind, cutting through aka leaving the raft behind, spontaneous clarity and so on. Compare to the advanced piano player.

So, yes, you can totally come to a Rime teacher as Theravada student, as long as both of you are clear where you are and where you are going. At some point you'll have to stop talking about "notes and scales" (the concepts you see in the Pali Canon) and start talking about "sparkles of joy" - the higher order concepts they teach at the Mahayana and Vajrayana levels. If that sounds exciting then you are a good Rime/Triyana material. If it sounds uncomfortable, you should probably stick to the regular Theravada.

P.S.

Another real-life gotcha: None of the Tibetan teachers will be as deeply educated in the Pali Canon as is customary in Theravada. They will have the basic concepts but don't expect them to know the hair-splitting nitty-gritties like the ones we analyze on this site. To draw on the piano allegory, they are not experts on hardcore music theory, at all. They do know the notes and that's where their knowledge of theory ends - their lineage is lineage of learning-by-doing and their ultimate focus is on soulful performance and that's what they teach.